# Replica Board of Samsung Horticulture Gen2 Module

Tags: led, led-driver, led-strip, constant-current, led-matrix

I want to make Replica board of Samsung Horticulture Gen2 Module but with smaller form factor.

I am using 42× LM301H (Full spectrum) and 8× LM351H LEDs.
I<sub>F</sub> of LM301H is 65 mA and I<sub>F</sub> of LH351H is 350 mA.

I have a constant current power supply of 420 mA and voltage can be adjusted to 25 to 40 volts. I am confused what series/parallel combination I should adopt as I am not using current limiting resistors or any other protection because Samsung did not use any protection other than a constant current power supply. Although I have designed a combination but I don't know if it will work or not.

Datasheets:

- [Samsung Horticulture Gen2 Module](https://download.led.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2022/01/%5BDatasheet%5D%20Standard%20Horticulture%20Gen2_REV1.1.pdf)
- [LM301H](https://download.led.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2022/05/Data_Sheet_LM301H_CRI80_Rev.5.4.pdf)
- [LH351H](https://download.led.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2022/05/Data_Sheet_LH351H_660nm_Red_V3_Rev.1.5.pdf)

[image: Schematic]

Comment: See [Are these LED circuits equivalent? (Samsung Standard Horticulture Gen2 Module)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/701469/are-these-led-circuits-equivalent-samsung-standard-horticulture-gen2-module) for good info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all the LM351H in series (due to higher current) and the LM301H in parallel strings (due to lower current limit) that are in series with the LM351H string as you did.  You're within the compliance voltage of your power supply and current should divide well within safe limits between the parallel strings, so I don't see any reason this won't work.

Note that since the aluminium PCB serves as the heatsink for that module that your maximum heat dissipation will decrease if you make that heatsink smaller.

Comment: There is one thing I forgot to mention that LM301H has forward voltage of 2.7V and Forward voltage of LM351H is 2.0V. Will it make some difference?

Comment: @ZunuranNasrullah Yes, it determines how many LEDs you can put in series.  However, the number you have will work as it is within the compliance voltage of the supply.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a close copy of the Gen2 circuit:

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 3c2g8eszq896]