# Are these LED circuits equivalent? (Samsung Standard Horticulture Gen2 Module)

Tags: led

Are these two circuits the same and equivalent?

Power supply: 42V, 300mA.

White LED, LM301H-EVO: 2.875V, 150mA.

Red660nm LED, LH351H: 1.875V, 300mA.

For some background, I'm looking at the Samsung Standard Horticulture Gen2 Module. [SI-B8T502560WW GEN2 Datasheet](https://led.samsung.com/lighting/led-modules/industrial-light-module/horticulture-module-gen2/).

Also, wondering does the module design use four of these types of circuits in parallel?

Thank you for any insight!

Edit: corrected uA to mA, and power supply is 300mA not 1200mA.
[image: TOP and BOTTOM circuits]

Comment: Please correct the unit: mA, not µA :)

Comment: I suppose you meant to write mA (milli) not uA (micro). On a side note, your choice of power supply doesn't seem right. You'd probably want a 300 mA constant current driver that's capable of 42V or more.

Answer (score 3):

They're not the same, but they will work more or less the same in terms of LED brightness. They will fail differently when one of the white LEDs burns out or if the LEDs are not well matched.

The advantage of the second circuit is it makes it easier to distribute the red LEDs evenly over the whole length of the module.

As to whether the module uses 4 of these in parallel: that's very likely, given that it specifies the same voltage and 4x the current of the circuit you're showing.

Note that the current rating of 1200 mA applies to the set of 4 -- the circuits you've drawn would only require 300 mA each. And the power supply should be a constant current driver with the right current, and capable of at least 42V.

Comment: This is great and "distribute the red LEDs evenly" is the exact type of information I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two schematics are not equivalent.

One of them has two parallel sets of 12 series LEDs in it.

The other has four series sections, each containing two parallel sets of 3 series LEDs.

The difference is, longest chain of those LEDs that are in series is either 12 or 3, which is a big difference.

Comment: Thank you. So would each work differently if provided with 42V and 300uA?

Comment: @Effexxess It would. LEDs have manufacturing tolerances. If one chain has LEDs with less voltage than nominal, it will draw more current than the chain with LEDs that have higher voltage than nominal. As you only have 2 chains, one could be brighter than other. Having smaller chains in series balances things out.

Comment: @Justme I would say it's the other way around. Assuming random sampling of Vf, longer chains will tend to be better matched than shorter chains.